# System default switchport shutdown on Arista EOS

Tags: switchport, arista, eos

Is there any equivalent to:

```
system default switchport shutdown
```

As available on Cisco's NX-OS to Arista EOS running with at least version 4.25.1F?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: The answers wasn’t working. There’s a comment on the answer regarding the issue.

Comment: I am just doing the year-end cleanup, and you may have solved it but not posted an answer, so this is just a friendly reminder. You can also post a bounty to get more interest in your question.

Comment: I'm just doing a year-end cleanup to see if we can get some questions answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Even though this is a bit late, but since this result popped up in my Google search, the way to do this is in Arista EOS is using (this also works for setting default MTU):

```
interface defaults
   ethernet
      shutdown
```

Comment: Unfortunately this command does not exist on EOS 4.25.1F. Only "interface defaults" is available: core01(config)#interface defaults ?
  <cr>

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão, The configuration option must be split into three lines: interface defaults<Enter>ethernet<Enter>shutdown